# Call Progress Procedure in kSoap

Tags: progress-4gl, ksoap, openedge, webspeed

I'm completely new with Progress. I'm trying to access my Progress Procedure (which works when I export it as an XML-page) in my Android app. I'm using kSoap to do the trick, because I've had some decent results of it.

But I can't seem to access my Progress Procedure in my Android project, can anyone help me to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there any helpful error messages?  (Or even unhelpful ones?)

Comment: No, I'm just getting a nullpointerException because my soapObject is null.

Comment: When I debug, I'm getting a connectException with a detailMessage: Localhost - Connection refused. I don't know if that's any helpful.

Comment: That sounds like you have the wrong host or port.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this? We're using the folowing link: http://localhost/scripts/cgiip.exe/WService=brAccentBe/testProc.p

Answer (score 0):

Hannelore, from your comment it looks like you're trying to access your .P via WebSpeed, which is not the same thing as WebServices (it's more of a normal web server).

The URL should look something like http://localhost:8080/wsa/wsa1 (depending on your config). You'll need to install the WSA (WebServicesAdapter from progress.com/esd if you don't have it already), and also something like Tomcat.

Lots more details in the OpenEdge doc ([here](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-103525)); specifically look at the [OpenEdge Development:Web Services](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/oe102bhtml/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=dvwsv&file=01dvwsvtitle.html) book

-- peter